# Adding conda to the PATH on macos Catalina

Tags: macos, anaconda

I downloaded the Anaconda individual edition 2020-2 graphical installer. And then by using the graphical wizard I installed Anaconda successfully in my macbook. I checked this by running the command conda --version it was giving the result of conda 4.8.2.
Next day when I opened the terminal and tried executing conda commands surprisingly I was getting command not found error. I checked the PATH by executing echo$PATH and found that Anaconda directory is not included in the path. I tried to add anaconda by running the following command:

```
export PATH="usr/local/bin:usr/bin:/bin:usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/anaconda3/bin"
```

After this conda commands were working on the same session but it was not when a new terminal window was opened. 
To fix this I opened the .bash_profile file in my home directory in vi editor and found that the following lines were already there in the file:

```
bash-3.2$ cat .bash_profile_bk

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

So I renamed the file to .bash_profile_bk by the following command

```
$mv .bash_profile .bash_profile_bk
```

Then created a new .bash_profile and added the export PATH line as follows

```
$vi .bash_profile
```

in vi editor:

```
export PATH="usr/local/bin:usr/bin:/bin:usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/anaconda3/bin"
```

I checked the content of the file:

```
bash-3.2$ cat .bash_profile

export PATH="/usr/bin:usr/local/bin:/bin:usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/anaconda3/bin"
```

exit the terminal session and then opened another terminal window. Typed the conda command but again it was not working:

```
bash-3.2$ conda --version
bash: conda: command not found
```

Can somebody suggest if I'm missing something? any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _I tried to add anaconda by running the following command:_ Adding Conda to your PATH is done by using the command `conda init`. Be careful when messing around with your .bash_profile, PATH, etc.

Comment: To quote [the docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/): _Should I add Anaconda to the macOS or Linux PATH?

We do not recommend adding Anaconda to the PATH manually. During installation, you will be asked “Do you wish the installer to initialize Anaconda3 by running conda init?” We recommend “yes”. If you enter “no”, then conda will not modify your shell scripts at all. In order to initialize after the installation process is done, first run source <path to conda>/bin/activate and then run conda init._